# Using the web-extension downloads API to inform a web page of the download status

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'd like to access the web extension downloads API for a particular set of web pages only.  I just want to be able to know if and when a file created on the client has been successsfully downloaded to the hard disk.

I understand the examples that modify something on a web page automatically or through an extension UI; but I don't understand how, or if, a web page gets information about extension API events.

It seems like it should be simple enough to do but I'm not understanding something basic.

Does the content script of the extension have access to the downloads API, or do only the background scripts and the content script has to listen for a message from the background script to know the status of the download?

Can the save-to-disk still be intitiated by a button click in the web page's JS code, as well as the code for what to do for each event of the download?

How does the web page's JS know which event the downloads API fired?

Or, do I add a button to the page, through the content script, and attach the events in the content script and have the content script also invoke the functions in the page's JS based on the download events?

Thank you.

This might be what is needed: https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/page-to-extension-messaging.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts.

It covers how the content script communicates with the web page, and how the content script communicates with the background script.

Also, the content script does not have access to the downloads API directly, but does indirectly through communicating with the background script.